# Generating flame graphs for a whole Java program execution

Tags: java, perf, flamegraph

I'm trying to generate a [Flame Graph](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html) for a Java program, using [perf-map-agent](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/perf-map-agent). I know that you can use `perf-java-record-stack` to record data for a running process. I have also found out that you may use the script `jmaps` in the Flame Graph directory. I have found [Brendan Gregg's example](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html#Java) as well as [a Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940627/ubuntu-16-04-lts-how-to-enable-symbols-for-the-perf-tool) illustrating this. However, in none of these examples the Java process is given as an argument to `perf record` (which means that perf collects stack traces for the entire system).

I want to record profiling data for the whole execution of the program (and preferably nothing else). Is there any way to do this? I have tried:

```
perf record -a -g java -XX:+PreserveFramePointer <other JVM arguments> <my java program>; sudo ~/bin/brendangregg/FlameGraph/jmaps
```

which answers:

```
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 1.711 MB perf.data (3449 samples) ]
Fetching maps for all java processes...
Mapping PID 2213 (user malin):
wc(1):   2970   9676 156108 /tmp/perf-2213.map
```

always with the same PID. This PID is a running process, not the one I tried to record data for.

Comment: have you tried to just omit `-a` to limit recording to the new java process?

Comment: `-a` means 'record profile info from all cores', not 'record from all processes'. The JVM may run on more than 1 core, and my program is multi threaded as well.

Comment: That's not true, the documentation may be misleading. See also `--cpu` in the documentation. If you specify a command, `perf record` will record events on all cores of all threads from the particular process.

Comment: And if I specify `-a`, it will record events of all processes?

Anyhow, the issue is that I want to record events for the whole process, that is not attaching to a running process. If I just run perf record and thereafter generate a report of a flame graph, it won't show me the names of the Java methods. Therefore I need to use `perf-java-record-stack`or `jmaps`, but I can only find examples of how they can be used for a process that is already running.

Comment: Why not use [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler)?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want might be:

1. run the `perf record` with `-a -g` constantly, before the java application get fired up.
2. run `jmap` while the Java application running, so that you can collect the JIT related symbols.
3. End the `perf record` after the java application finished.
4. filter the output of `perf script` by the `pid` you are interested in. At that time, your Java process is already running, and you know what pid it is. (open the output of the `perf script` to have a look, you will know how to filter)
5. Run the flamegraph generation script.

In this way you can have the Java application recorded for the whole period of time.